# Is it possible get Android MediaPlayer sessionID for QMediaPlayer, Qt 5.9?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, qmediaplayer

The question is in title indeed... Qt's QMediaPlayer uses internal Android MediaPlayer to play music. MediaPlayer has it's own session ID. But how to get it from C++ or Java code? Of course there is MediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId() call - but how get MediaPlayer started by QMediaPlayer()??